# Does scalardb support timestamp type? If now, is text or blob the best way to store timestamp?

Tags: scalardb

Does scalardb support timestamp type? If not, is the best way to store timestamp a text or blob or some other type?

Would this schema now work?

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    token_id text PRIMARY KEY,
    email text,
    expiration_time timestamp,
..
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

I think the best solution depends.
Using BIGINT and storing Unix timestamp in it is one of the space efficient ways, but it requires a conversion every time.
As an alternative, we can use TEXT and store string formatted datetime, but it uses more space.